# Sinon doesn't work with Q promises

Tags: javascript, q, sinon

I have been using sinon for very long time and it worked perfectly. But now we are started to use Q promises, looks like things are breaking with sinon spies.

For example:

```
var spy = sandbox.spy(someApi,"callFn")
// success: return a promise fulfilled with `5`:
someStub.withArgs("foo").returns(Q.resolve(5));
```

I could able to do this, which in turn resolves the promise. I could able to see that the `then` block of promise is executing by adding an `console.log` statement:

```
promise.then(function(){
  console.log("comes here") // <---- gets printed
  someApi.callFn() // <--- spies on this are failing
})
```

Even though the `callFn`is called, `spy` still says `callCount` is `0`. I'm really not sure, why sinon wasn't able to spy an function which is called inside the promise `then` block.

Am I missing something here? Kindly let me know in order to fix my problem.

Comment: First of all to have promise support in sinon you would use https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon-as-promised. And are you writing unit tests for Node.js or front-end platform?

Comment: @KirillSlatin: Front end platform

Comment: @KirillSlatin: Thanks, but I'm using `Q` promises, standalone, not angular!

Comment: *When* does it say that the `callCount` is `0`? After that log statement was executed? Don't forget that the `then` callback is asynchronous.

Comment: @Bergi: after the `then` block, if I do: `console.log(spy.callCount)` it says `0`.

Comment: @batman: Yes, that's expected. It's [***asynchronous***](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572)! Right after the `.then(…)` block the handler has only been installed, but not yet executed.

Comment: @Bergi: So how should I handle this in the test cases?

Comment: @batman: You'll need to write asynchronous test cases. Depends on your testing platform how to do that exactly.